# Can't see Angular project inside Django

Tags: django, angular

I am trying to run Angular inside Django project. I successfully installed it and have no errors when I run the Django server. However I do not see my Angular. app.component.html. I see my index.html of folder "templates" instead.

templates/index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
  <p>This is a mini-blog application using a back-end built on Django 2.0 and Django Rest Framework. It illustrates how to create and send JSON Web Token authentication headers with the HTTP requests.</p>

  <app-root>Loading the app...</app-root>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'clientapp/runtime.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'clientapp/polyfills.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'clientapp/styles.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'clientapp/vendor.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'clientapp/main.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Obviously, something is missing.
I am using this tutorial and looks like copied all the setttings:
https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-api-calls-django-authentication-jwt
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django, Angular is nothing more than a set of static files.
So in order to make sure everything falls in its place, we need to load static files in order of their preference.

I suggest you visit `index.html` generated by webpack, just copy that order of javascript files in Django `index.html` in Django format.

For More info visit your browser console for errors.

For Ref: https://github.com/deepak1725/djangular

Comment: @Deepack Sharma Thanks for quick response. Isn't it what I am doing in my sample templates/index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is absolutely silly as in my case. 
I used old ng build.
Each time after change links to static files we need to run ng build